Laravel translation not working with javascript variable
I worked on a Laravel project, to get the content of a div with Ajax call and Jquery, I did like that in blade template:
    results[k].items.map((result,index) => (
                                                $(".kf_opponents_wrap2").append(

                                    '<div class="kf_opponents_wrap">\
                                    <h6 class="kf_h4">\
                                        <em>'+((result.fixture.status.elapsed == null ||   result.fixture.status.elapsed == 90) ? getMatchTime(result.fixture.timestamp) : result.fixture.status.elapsed)+'</em>\
                                    </h6>\
                                        <div class="kf_opponents_dec">\
                                            <span><img src="'+result.teams.home.logo+'" alt=""></span>\
                                            <div class="text">\
                                                <h6><a href="#">'+result.teams.home.name+'</a></h6>\
                                            </div>\

    ......
    )

Until now everything is ok and the div is correctly displayed using Ajax call, the next issue is how to make translation inside append and using javascript variable and not php variable inside the Laravel function echo __('.....');
<a href="#">echo __('+result.teams.home.name+');</a> // I know is wrong because is confusion between client side and server side.

I tried to use https://github.com/rmariuzzo/Laravel-JS-Localization but is not working for me at all.
My question is how to use Laravel translation inside javascript using javascript variable inside or another way to use php or get the translation from DB? Any idea?

Presumably your AJAX call is calling a Laravel route, you can translate the relevant parts in that route before sending it to the client

In that case I must make translation in controller but is not a professional way I guess! and If yes can you clarify your idea?

You can create an endpoint to return all translation keys and use it on JS application
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

public function getAllTranslations()
{
    $languages = ['en', 'es', 'fr']; // Add more languages as needed
    $translations = [];

    foreach ($languages as $lang) {
        $translations[$lang] = [];

        // Assuming your translations are in the resources/lang directory
        $files = File::allFiles(resource_path("lang/$lang"));

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $filename = pathinfo($file)['filename'];
            $translations[$lang][$filename] = trans($filename, [], $lang);
        }
    }

    return response()->json($translations);
}

And this on routers/api.php
use App\Http\Controllers\YourController;

Route::get('/translations', [YourController::class, 'getAllTranslations']);


Ok and how to link that and use it in blade template?
